# PHP sql anywhere connection issues

Tags: php, sybase, sqlanywhere

I want to access a remote Sybase Database with PHP and the module SQLANYWHERE. I installed it and tested that it worked properly like this:

```
if( ! extension_loaded('sqlanywhere') )  print("<b>SQL ANYWHRE not available</b>". "\xA") ;
```

I then tried if I can even reach the DB-Server like this:

```
$host = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; 
$port = xxxx; 
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
   print("<b> SQL Verbindung established</b>". "\xA");
} else {
   print("<b>keine SQL not established</b>". "\xA");
} 
fclose($fp);
```

which also worked.
But I just can't connect, here is my connection string:

```
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.";port=".$port.")";
$conn=sasql_connect($connString);
```

all the values are correctly configured since it worked in the first try above.

But when I try to load my page I always get this error:

```
Warning: sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-832] Verbindungsfehler: Fehler in den TCPIP Portoptionen in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 59
sasql_connect failed
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 75
```

the first line means "Connection Error: Error in the TCPIP port options"

**EDIT: These are all the different connStrings i already tried:**

```
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";Server=".$serverName.";host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";host‌​=".$server.";port=".$port;
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server."Port=".$port.")";
```

**SOLUTION**

I found out that the SQL Anywhere installation you need for the PHP module has a cmdline tool called [dbping](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/da-conparm.html) included. copying my string from my text editor to the cmdline i noticed there where unprintable characters in my string which the cmdline couldn't resolve and printed them as "??". after rewriting the part where the characters were, the connection works. kill me... 2 days for this.

Comment: *Warning: sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-832] Verbindungsfehler: Fehler in den TCPIP Portoptionen in* can you translate it to English?

Comment: The last sentence in my question is the translation :)

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see :)

Comment: So, you have a problem here `CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.";port=".$port.")";`, more specifically here `$port`. Did you check SqlAnywhere docs about possible troubleshooting?

Comment: I really don't know what to look for, the port is open and I can access it from the machine the code is running on, the docs are saying that the error code -832 stands for an "connection issue". there are less informations about the error in the docs than in the error message

Comment: Have you tried to pass `$port` as a string? Just a guess... Where your define `$port = xxxx;`, try `$port = 'xxxx';`

Comment: Good idea, I'll try it. But as you see I already write everything into a string variable, isn't it the same?

Comment: Logically, I agree with you. But computers... they're crazy.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self explanatory; What is at line 59? Is that this line:

```
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.";port=".$port.")";
```

Essentially your port isn't correct. You are also trying to call the `close()` method on an object that doesn't exist.

I read through some documentation (http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/links.html) and it looks like your string should actually look like this:

```
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
```

Note that this appends the port to the host (host:1337), instead of giving it an explicit `port` key.

Comment: Yes, line 59 is where the `connString` is called. 
The port is correct, I used it to connect to the DB server through another tool, the values are correct.
I tried to use your connString but appending the port to the host didn't helped either.

Comment: Going further through the documentation I provided, is there a reason you are using the `CommLinks` parameter instead of the `Host` parameter?

Comment: If you found a doc where this process is explained please let me have a link.

Comment: I found this recommended method as apposed to the CommLinks key you are using: http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/host-con-parm.html

Comment: just tried this connString: `$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";` with this one the error message disappears, but the connection is still not established

Comment: Have you tried using the `sybase` module for PHP instead of the `sqlanywhere`? http://php.net/manual/en/book.sybase.php

Comment: See update in question, got the solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Run your database like this:
/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/dbeng17 -x tcpip /path/to/database/database.db

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with connecting to database.
Just try run your sqlanywhere database like this:

```
./bin64/dbeng17 -x tcpip /path/to/database/database.db
```

This trigger "-x tcpip" is important to connect php with database.